# tutorials on how to create a database in python?

Tags: python, database

I'm looking to start building a database with python so I can make more dynamic web pages and just as a project and I want it to just be stored as a file like a .db file but I can't find any intermediate friendly tutorials or tutorials that arent online cloud options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, 
tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract 
opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) 
and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/

Comment: There are roughly a billion tutorial pages describing how to get starting with databases in Python.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively powerful option for Python is `sqlite3` from the stdlib.

You can find tutorials for this in places like [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sqlite3+python) and [sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/)

And for better understanding of how the library was intended to be used, visit the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) on Python's website